# Does repairing Windows format the drive?

Tags: windows-xp, system-restore

I need to repair my Windows XP, but I am not sure if I still can have all my files in the same hard disk drive.

so there is option to `repair`, will I get my files erased if I choose that options?

Comment: No,it just reinstalls windows on the same drive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't erase any data - just update the files under c:\windows (or wherever you installed windows to).

Having said that it would be prudent to back up your data first - if necessary by plugging your hard-drive into another computer - just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You should also back up at least your own directory under C:\Documents and Settings (or whatever drive you've installed Windows on).

There's a good set of instructions for reinstalling Windows (including XP) at http://pcworld.about.com/magazine/2109p156id111652.htm. I used this recently on one of my machines - worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If shouldn't format the drive, but it will delete corrupted files and folders. Backup is definitely recommended before you attempt a repair. You may lose corrupted files if they are windows system files.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm "Repairing" Windows XP **WILL NOT** delete your normal files.

Although, some things that you need to take in to consideration:

- If you have SP2/3 installed for instance and you repair from a SP1 CD it will revert (usually badly) back to SP1 this can be remedied by using the network installation versions of the SP pack you used to have to have installed.
- As per the previous note, windows applications like Windows Messenger and Windows Media Player will glitch back to the previous versions, easily fixed by reinstalling the versions you had but you will get some nasty errors if you try and use them without reinstalling the version you used to have.

Hope that helped!